# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDatabaseContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

After deleting migration folder and database from ssms I got this error when running add-migration command.

This is my ApplicationDatabaseContext :

```
public class ApplicationDatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }
    public DbSet<CommentGroup> CommentGroup { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Websites> Websites { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "User");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserClaims");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserLogins");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserTokens");
        });
    }
}
```

I just deleted the migration folder and database from ssms and run add-migration command.

Comment: where is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by adding a empty constructor in AplicationDatabaseContext.cs.